# Android - how to change layout inside include tag on click?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

[image: A drawing to explain my problem - how to switch from layout B to layout C while keeping the same layout A?]

I am developing an app in android studio using kotlin. I am new to the android development.

I encountered the following problem:
I want to switch from layout B to layout C on button click while keeping the same layout A.

If it was a single screen, I could just make an activity and switch to/from it. However, I use `<include>` tags and need to keep the screen split.

What's the best way to do it? All that comes to my mind is overlapping the layouts and playing with visibility, but there's no way there's not a better way to do it, right?

How do I swap the layout of an include tag during runtime?

Comment: Have a look at Fragments. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments for that kind of behavior; you can tell the fragmentManager to switch Fragments in your Activity. You will need a FrameLayout to act as a container.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui

Since it seems you want to replace the current view B to C you can use the replace method to achieve your expected behavior.

Welcome to the world of Fragments!